# How to get cpu utlization using cpu_ticks data from sys.dm_os_sys_info

Tags: sql-server

There are many references on web for this query `SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info` to obtain cpu utilization.
How does this query work ?

Comment: Why not just try it?  It'd not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: Microsoft document on cpu_ticks  reads like this - "specifies the current CPU tick count. CPU ticks are obtained from the processor's RDTSC counter. It is a monotonically increasing number" . Nothing much.  How is this translated into CPU utilization ? I am looking for some explanation on  the expression cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks).

Comment: Can you provide a reference where you saw that formula recommended?  I have not seen it before and i'd need to read the source article to figure out why they aren't just using `ms_ticks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As near as I can tell, this is a mistake.  It apparently was an attempt to convert the formula from SQL Server 2005:

```
cpu_ticks / sys.cpu_ticks_in_ms
```

With it's equivalent from SQL Server 2008, when the `cpu_ticks_in_ms` (the number of cpu ticks in a millisecond) was replaced with `ms_ticks` (the number of milliseconds since boot).  Apparently someone just figured since `cpu_ticks_in_ms = (cpu_ticks / ms_ticks)` they would just sub that in to:

```
cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks)
```

Of course, that's dumb since that is the same as:

```
ms_ticks
```

So I'd just use `ms_ticks`.

You can see the earliest reference to this (outside of a hidden sign-on site) [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abbf67ab-fc8b-4567-b6d4-1c605bc9866c/2008-missing-sysdmossysinfocputicksinms?forum=sqldatabaseengine) where the last poster asks the same question but never receives an answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for confirming that that was a mistake and it actually translates to just ms_ticks.